# Windows 10 with Blender won't change gpu percentage during rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu, windows

I have built a new Desktop PC with an unactivated version of Windows 10 to run with Blender and haven't gotten it to fully work yet. I've downloaded the latest Nvidia drivers from Nvidia's GeForce Experience and updated Blender with CUDA and GPU Compute. I've even added Blender to Nvidia's Control Panel to make sure it was working there. I also have the OpenGL file in the Blender directory to make sure that I have OpenGL.

When I first open Blender and try to render out the basic scene with the generic cube with lighting and the camera, Blender works fine. As soon as I go back to Blender from the UI window Blender is slow as can be and is lagging for seconds just to change from the top view to the front view. This is not even close to what I want to do with Blender.

I've tested the rendering scene with the task manager to make sure that the CPU isn't rendering the scene and that the GPU is rendering it with GPU Compute but there's no percentage change for the GPU during the rendering phase that the task manager can tell. The CPU is still going up in percentage like it's still taking the full load. I'm not even sure what's up with Blender. I know for a fact it's running the GPU during the rendering scene for all the tiny rendering squares but something else is not working and I can't seem to find out why.

**Does anybody know what would cause Blender to be so slow and lagging after a rendering scene like this?? Also does anyone else notice if their GPU percentage goes up during their rendering phases?**

I'm at a stand still and don't know what to do next. The components I'm using on my PC are: Intel core i5, ASUS PRIME Z270-A, a ASUS Dual Series GEFORCE GTX 1050 and two 4GB Kingston HyperFury DDR4 Memory cards.

Comment: "*Does anybody know what would cause Blender to be so slow*" Probably that OpenGL file you put in there. Why would you do that? "*I know for a fact it's running the GPU during the rendering scene for all the tiny rendering squares*" If it has lots of tiny squares then it is most definitely **not** running on the GPU, each square most often represents one CPU thread.

Comment: Putting OpenGL.dll into directory with Blender doesn't ensure you have OpenGL, it makes Blender open in legacy mode without even relying on graphics which allows running it in environments without graphic card available (remote connection for example). Blender *will* work slowly with that file in its directory